# Deleting duplicates in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Currently, I use a table with no primary keys. So while loading the table, there are possibilities that duplicates may be loaded.

I use an automated process to load the table and a delete script in that process deletes the dubplicates from the table. But records which are not duplicates also get deleted. I am not able to figure out why. Please give your inputs.

Table Name : Employee

Table after Loading before deletion script runs

```
EmpID   SalID   EmpName   EmpAddr     EmpZip    
 112     012     Smith      TN        641604    
 112     012     Smith      TN        641604    
 113     013     Steve      KA        560068    
 114     014     Rao        KA        560069    
 115     015     Ram        KA        560100    
 115     015     Ram        KA        560100
```

Table after deletion script runs

```
EmpID   SalID   EmpName   EmpAddr     EmpZip    
 112     012     Smith      TN        641604    
 114     014     Rao        KA        560069    
 115     015     Ram        KA        560100
```

Strangely, EmpId 113 is deleted, while EmpId 114 is retained.

Below is the deletion script

```
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE E1 WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE E2 WHERE E2.EMPID = E1.EMPID 
AND E2.SALID = E1.SALID AND E2.EMPNAME = E1.EMPNAME
AND E2.EMPADDR = E1.EMPADDR AND E2.EMPZIP = E1.EMPZIP
AND E2.ROWID > E1.ROWID)
```

Kindly give your inputs on whats going wrong.

Comment: What's going wrong is that you are not using primary keys.

Comment: unfortunately, that is the requirement.

Comment: Your `DELETE` script works perfectly fine with the example data provided, so - as bob dylan pointed out in their answer - I guess this is not your *real* data. Please provide a *complete*, *reproducible* example (adding a SQL fiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Rowid = something like that : AAAIVuAABAAAMhCAAA

"Greater than" work, but not like expected, it's not a numerical value like "rownum".

You should try with "E2.ROWID <> E1.ROWID" instead of  "E2.ROWID > E1.ROWID", it's the usual way to clean duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your real data isn't what's in your example.

Using Rowid is a strange way of filtering though. I presume you want the last one? In which case rowid *may* be the latest one, but it all depends on how it was loaded too and isn't necessarily the best indicator of the row. If you've only got this data to work from do you even care about the rowid?

This is what I get:

```
Create table emp1 (EmpID varchar(20),  SalID   varchar(20),EmpName   varchar(20),EmpAddr     varchar(20),EmpZip  varchar(20));
insert into emp1 values ('112',     '012',     'Smith',      'TN',        '641604');    
insert into emp1 values ('112',     '012',     'Smith',      'TN',        '641604'); 
insert into emp1 values ('113',     '013',     'Steve',      'KA',        '560068') ;
insert into emp1 values ('114',     '014',     'Rao',      'KA',        '560069') ;
insert into emp1 values ('115',     '015',     'Ram',      'KA',        '560100') ;
insert into emp1 values ('115',     '015',     'Ram',      'KA',        '560100') ;


DELETE FROM EMP1 E1 WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM EMP1 E2 WHERE E2.EMPID = E1.EMPID 
AND E2.SALID = E1.SALID AND E2.EMPNAME = E1.EMPNAME
AND E2.EMPADDR = E1.EMPADDR AND E2.EMPZIP = E1.EMPZIP
AND E2.ROWID > E1.ROWID);


select * from emp1;
112 012 Smith   TN  641604
113 013 Steve   KA  560068
114 014 Rao KA  560069
115 015 Ram KA  560100
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e2190/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowid` to distinguish duplicate entries from each other is a perfectly acceptable way to do this as soon as you don't have any other identifier.

```
SQL> select * from emp1
  2  /

EMPID    SALID    EMPNAME  EMPADDR  EMPZIP
-------- -------- -------- -------- ------
112      012      Smith    TN       641604
112      012      Smith    TN       641604
113      013      Steve    KA       560068
114      014      Rao      KA       560069
115      015      Ram      KA       560100
115      015      Ram      KA       560100

6 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> delete from emp1
  2  where rowid not in (
  3      select min(rowid)
  4      from emp1
  5      group by EmpID, SalID,EmpName,EmpAddr,EmpZip
  6  )
  7  /

2 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> select * from emp1
  2  /

EMPID    SALID    EMPNAME  EMPADDR  EMPZIP
-------- -------- -------- -------- ------
112      012      Smith    TN       641604
113      013      Steve    KA       560068
114      014      Rao      KA       560069
115      015      Ram      KA       560100

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

Answer (score 0):

When the order of row is not important.

```
DELETE FROM 
   emp1 A
WHERE 
  a.rowid > ANY (SELECT B.rowid FROM emp1 B WHERE a.EmpID = b.EmpId and a.SalID = b.SalID and  a.EmpName = b.EmpName);
```

Or when order is important.

```
delete from 
   emp1
where rowid in
 (select rowid from 
   (select rowid, row_number() over (partition by EmpID, SalID , EmpName order by /*column to order row*/ EmpID) row_no from emp1)
  where row_no > 1);
```